# Python-Imaging-Library only paste imageparts with 255 alpha

Tags: python, python-imaging-library

I want to use `paste` of the python `PIL` library to paste a image to a black background.

I know I can use the image itself as a alpha mask, **but** I only want to have the parts of the image where the alpha value is *255*.

How is this possible?

Here is my code so far:

```
import PIL
from PIL import Image

img = Image.open('in.png')
background = Image.new('RGBA', (825, 1125), (0, 0, 0, 255))

offset = (50, 50)

background.paste(img, offset, img) #image as alpha mask as third param
background.save('out.png')
```

I can't find anything in the official but bad [documentation](http://effbot.org/imagingbook/image.htm)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, then
this is a possible solution. It generates
a dedicated mask, which is used for the paste:

```
from PIL import Image

img = Image.open('in.png')

# Extract alpha band from img
mask = img.split()[-1]
width, height = mask.size

# Iterate through alpha pixels,
# perform desired conversion
pixels = mask.load()
for x in range(0, width):
    for y in range(0, height):
        if pixels[x,y] < 255:
            pixels[x,y] = 0

# Paste image with converted alpha mask
background = Image.new('RGBA', (825, 1125), (0, 0, 0, 255))
background.paste(img, (50, 50), mask)
background.save('out.png')
```

As a note, the alpha channel of the background image is fairly useless.
If you don't need it later on, you could also load the background with:

```
background = Image.new('RGB', (825, 1125), (0, 0, 0))
```

Comment: Well, thats the perfect solution, i was just to stuipid to think of creating my own mask. thanks a lot